# Focused value when clicking on selectList in visualforce page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, salesforce, visualforce

I am using selectList tag in my visualforce page, this selectList contains years number (2001,2002,...,2020) as follows:

```
 <apex:selectList id="mySelect" styleClass="form_field flex_grow" required="true" multiselect="false" size="1" label="Type"  value="{!selectedYear}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Years}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

The values of year comes from a method from the controller (it is already populated). The first item appears on the selectList is 2001

What I want to do is when I click the selectList to display years values I want the focused value in the list not to be 2001 but 2010 ( once i click the selectList to display list of years  i want the focused value to be 2010).

Here is the source code I have implemented but it doesn't work:

```
$('#mySelect').focus(function(){

    if($(this).data('focused') !==  true)
    {
        $(this).data('focused',true);  
        $(this).find('option[value="2010"]').prop('selected',true);
    }

});

$('#mySelect').blur(function(){
   $(this).data('focused',false); 
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JS functions for that, just check out that you populate selectedYear variable with correct value (2010) in controller.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want the value to be appeared from scratch I want the cursor to be focused on that value once i click the selectList

Comment: In such case you wrongly get copmponents by ID in JS - you can't use ID directly, because visualforce tag IDs are not equal to IDs in HTML (you can check it if open page source in browser). For more detailds check out [Using $Component to Reference Components from JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm).

Comment: Yea @Hleb I noticed that before, but is not there any other solution to do that ?

Comment: Actually, this is most easiest (and commonly used) way to get Visualforce component's IDs from JavaScript, although is not the most convenient for reading.